# scikit learn test_data_split: ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples:[4999, 5000]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

Here is my code

```
print(len(image_dataset.data))
print(len(phylum_target))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(image_dataset.data, phylum_target, test_size=0.2,random_state=109)
```

And here is output and Error

```
5000
5000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Image_SVM_run_only.py", line 298, in <module>
    X_train_temp, X_test_temp, y_train_temp, y_test_temp = train_test_split(image_dataset.data, phylum_target, test_size=0.2,random_state=109)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/IBC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2127, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/IBC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 293, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/root/anaconda3/envs/IBC/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 257, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4999, 5000]
```

Even though train data and test data have same length, I've got this error.
Please help me T.T

Comment: More than just length, what is the length / shape[0] of each?

Comment: `
print(type(image_dataset.data)) 
print(type(phylum_target)) 
print(image_dataset.data.shape) 
print(phylum_target.shape)
`

 
`<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
(5000, 49152)
(5000, 1)`

Comment: image_dataset.data[0].shape is (49152,), and phylum_target[0].shape is (1,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the minimum reproducible example I can discern from your info and works just fine

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = np.zeros((5000, 49152))
y = np.zeros((5000, 1))
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=109)
print(X_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_train.shape, y_test.shape)
```

Comment: your code works, but mine still doesn't...
thanks for help

Comment: No problem Changwan, to debug I'd say just backtrack from the above code and make sure that your "image_dataset.data, phylum_target" objects truly are the same as the "X, y" in the above code right before the call. Maybe you accidentally consumed a piece at some point, popped or removed -- something else??

Comment: It seems to be data problem as this dataset was from really big one, and generated by codes with multiprocessing, I found some of the data contain some invalid strings.... while I don't know why it has "some" invalid strings but error message saids only one difference... Thanks for help anyway!